# Looking for a generic dependency management tool for multiple languages

Tags: dependencies, dependency-management

I’m looking for assistance with finding a generic dependency management tool for a specific scenario.

We have a few repositories, each of them has a build process which eventually publishes zips (with msis and exes) and jars to artifactory.
We have another repository that contains mostly c and perl code which in the end is packaged with the artifacts from the repositories above.

We need a tool that we will be able to pull from the artifactory the latest (or specific) artifacts, extract them in pre-defined hierarchy.

Is there something that might work for it except writing and maintaining our own script?
The catch here is that we have multiple languages and the solutions that we found are usually language specific or without spec files.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

The solution that we adopted was to use maven with Artifactory for the dependencies and gradle for building the projects that already use it - because it's a mixture of teams that works on different technologies...